# Monitor not detected via DisplayPort - Ubuntu 16.04, ATI graphics card

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, displayport

I have connected two monitors to my graphics card: one is connected via DisplayPort to HDMI adapter and it works fine; the second is connected directly via DisplayPort and it isn't detected by my OS.

When I run `xrandr`, I can see that DisplayPort is disconnected so my monitor was not detected. When I turn on the computer, Grub is displayed on both monitors, so this isn't a connection problem.

I read some posts on a forum, and as someone wrote I disabled DDC/CI in the monitor, but it didn't help. Could you give me some advice how to resolve this problem?

Graphics card: ATI FirePro V8700, card is detected correctly

Regards, Pawel

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I have AMD graphics and two dell displays. The one connected by dual-dvi works flawlessly, but the one that uses displayport turns off after a few minutes.